# Using SOAP/XML-RPC request as a Monitor in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using jmeter to submit a few SOAP messages to the application engine. I need a monitor that can collect some of the application engine's performance statistics. But the only option to query the application statistics is to send a different SOAP message to the application.

How can I use a SOAP/XML-RPC request sampler as a monitor? I can't use HTTP request as a monitor since there's no corresponding HTTP service to retrieve monitor results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually as per [Creating WebService Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html#soap_webservice_template) it is recommended to use [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to perform SOAP calls. HTTP Request Sampler has "Use as Monitor" checkbox

[image: HTTP Request SOAP]

Don't forget to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) in order to send correct [Content-Type](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) and [SOAPAction](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/post/unraveling_the_mystery_of_soap.html) headers.

Comment: This works, but my monitor is returning an error - `\jmeter.threads.ListenerNotifier: Detected problem in Listener:  java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.MonitorAccumModel.addSample(MonitorAccumModel.java:166)`. My web service response is something like this: `<soapenv:Envelope><soapenv:Body><ns1:MemoryUsage><ns1:memoryUsageStatistics memoryType="IN_USE"><ns1:memoryUsageStatistic time="2016-07-12T01:00:00.000-05:00">3097</ns1:memoryUsageStatistic>..`